# Looping through image array and loop breaks with missing image

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I have an array of image urls and I'm looping through them every time the user presses a 'next' button. However, this loop breaks when it comes across a missing image. Any idea how the loop can continue? I'm replacing a missing image with a static one using the jQuery error function. The loop works perfectly without missing images... It just kinda stops when it detects a 404 error.

This is a sample of my code:

```
var $img = $(".testImg") 
for(var i = 0; i < imgUrls.length;i++) {
    if(imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src")) {
      if(i === (imgUrls.length-1)) {
        $img.attr("src",imgUrls[0]).error(function(){
          $(this).attr('src', 'images/missing.png')
        })
        break
      }
      $img.attr("src",imgUrls[i+1]).error(function(){
        $(this).attr('src', 'images/missing.png')
      })
      break
  }
}
```

SOLUTION (thanks to Jose below):

```
var $img = $("#vImg") 
      $img.show()
      $("#missingImg").hide()
      for(var i = 0; i < imgUrls.length;i++) {
        if(imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src")) {
          if(i === (imgUrls.length-1)) {
            $img.error(function(){
              $("#vImg").hide()
              $("#missingImg").show()
            }).attr("src",imgUrls[0])
            break
          }
          $img.error(function(){
            $("#vImg").hide()
            $("#missingImg").show()
          }).attr("src",imgUrls[i+1])
          break
        }
      }
```

I'm sure my code could do with being a bit neater though... ;)

Comment: It breaks because you're using the `break` keyword.

Comment: replace break with continue

Comment: what do u mean 'missing image'? in the array you have an empty string instead of a src?

Comment: @Scimonster `break` keyword **is not the reason**. That `attr` runs only once. He is using `break` just as a loop optimization, since there is no need to complete the loop, when he finds the current url (`if(imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src"))`).

Comment: Sorry, to clarify... My image array is made up of absolute urls. I threw in a url which I know has no image to test with. If I replace break with continue, the loop stops working all together. Maybe I need to rethink how I am doing this.

Comment: @WastedSpace please check my answer. I might found the reason why your next button fails.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are defining `error` handler after setting the url, which is wrong.

When you do this:

```
$img.attr("src", "someInvalidURL.png").error(yourErrorHandler)
```

`yourErrorHandler` is never called in case of a 404 (or any other error) because you are registering the `error` handler after changing the attribute `src`.

You need to register the `error` event first, and only then fire the request (change the `src`).

```
$img.error(yourErrorHandlerThatWorks).attr("src", "someInvalidURL.png")
```

Also, every time you click the next button, you re-registering again the `error` event. You can and should register only once:

```
$(".testImg").error(function() {
      $(this).attr('src', 'images/missing.png')
});
```

and then your next Button code can be:

```
for(var i = 0; i < imgUrls.length;i++) {
    if(imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src")) {
      if(i === (imgUrls.length-1)) {
        $img.attr("src",imgUrls[0])
        break
      }

      $img.attr("src",imgUrls[i+1])
      break
  }
}
```

---

Edit:

Now I understand why your next button stops working.

When you have an error, you are setting the $img url to `images/missing.png`. Then, obviously, the "Next" button will never do anything, because the condition `imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src")` will always be false (that condition will work as `imgUrls[i] == "images/missing.png"`.

You need to do something else in the error handler, such using another `<img>` with a missing image that is always hidden and only appears when you have an error.

Comment: Great - that's it! Thanks very much. Obvious really! Sometimes when you stare at things too long... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Throw away your `break`-statements and use a proper `if`-`else`-cascade instead like so:

```
var $img = $(".testImg");
for (var i = 0; i < imgUrls.length; i++) {
    if (imgUrls[i] == $img.attr("src")) {
        if (i === (imgUrls.length - 1)) {
            $img.attr("src", imgUrls[0]).error(function () {
                $(this).attr('src', 'images/missing.png');
            });
        } else {
            $img.attr("src", imgUrls[i + 1]).error(function () {
                $(this).attr('src', 'images/missing.png');
            });
        }
    }
}
```

This way, you loop runs until the end and doesn't stop in between..

if you insist in using your code, you have to remove the last `break` statement as it makes the `for`-loop stop in case there is no URL provided. The first one should be ok, if it is okay for the loop to stop if the URL has been found But honestly i think my suggestion is a bit cleaner, even though this sound a bit arrogant ;)

Comment: Thanks, but I only need to show one image at a time. I should have been clearer. My code is inside a function which runs every time the user clicks the next button. When clicking the next button it shows the next image in the array. When it comes across a missing image, it correctly shows the missing.png, but then the next button stops working...